# Zprofile errors on Terminal Startup (MacOS)

Tags: shell, terminal, homebrew, environment

I'm getting errors whenever I startup my terminal- I got a new computer for bioinformatics, so it's relatively fresh. I haven't put much on here, except a couple basics- I suspect homebrew issues but I'm not sure where I went wrong. When I startup, I'm getting the following message just from opening Terminal:

```
Last login: Mon Jan 30 12:51:33 on ttys001
/Users/hdose/.zprofile:3: command not found: s
/Users/hdose/.zprofile:4: command not found: q
12:51  up 3 mins, 2 users, load averages: 112.81 28.51 10.54
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT
hdose    console  -                12:51       - -
hdose    s000     -                12:51       - w

/Users/hdose/.zprofile:6: command not found: e
/Users/hdose/.zprofile:fc:7: current history line would recurse endlessly, aborted
/Users/hdose/.zprofile:fc:8: current history line would recurse endlessly, aborted
/Users/hdose/.zprofile:9: command not found: t
/Users/hdose/.zprofile:10: permission denied: /
/Users/hdose/.zprofile:.:11: not enough arguments
/Users/hdose/.zprofile:12: command not found: ,
/Users/hdose/.zprofile:32: unmatched '
```

I've checked

```
$open -e \~/.zprofile
```

Which returns:

```
echo '# Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.' \>\> /Users/hdose/.zprofile

s
q
w
e
r
r
t
/
.
,
'
;
\\
> > 
\<\<
/
?

Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.

Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.

eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.

eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.

Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.

Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.

Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.

Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.

Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.

Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.
```

For some background, for home-brew install, I did:

```
$echo '# Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.' \>\> /Users/hdose/.zprofile
$echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' \>\> /Users/hdose/.zprofile
```

Comment: The `.zprofile` is in **your** home directory and completely under your control. **You** are the only person on this planet who can legally decide what's  in there. If you have garbage in this file, just make a backup (in case you want to admire it later on again) and erase its contents. Actually, you might want to place into it commands which are going to be executed by each zsh login shell, but if you don't anything which you want to be done at that occasion, it's fine too.

Comment: BTW, I don't know what exactly `open -e` is doing on the Mac, but to edit a file, you simply use your favorite text editor.

Comment: @user1934428 You solved it! 
    `open -e`
just opens the file in TextEdit where I just deleted all that trash per your recommendation. I didn't realize it was that simple and could just be erased without messing anything up, but looks clean! Thank you!